# implementing jquery fancybox over animated gradient background

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fancybox, gradient

I have an animated gradient background and I am trying to place a fancybox over it. The gradient and fancybox are in two different stacked divs, yet for some reason the gradient is blocking access to the clickable thumbnail. When I take the gradient div away, the fancybox works like a beauty. what should I do to make them compatible? site: http://studiopowell.net/TEST_gradient.html

```
</head>
<body>

<div id="titles"><img src="archive-icon.png" width="185" height="185" alt="studio powell michael powell studiopowell art artist books installation video" /><br /><br />&nbsp; M I C H A E L &nbsp; P O W E L L<br /><br /></div>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></a>

<div id="gradient"></div>

</body>
</html>

css:

.fancybox {
    margin:auto;
    width:10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
} 

 #titles {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#33;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;  
}

#gradient
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  margin-top: -600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply CSS `position` and `z-index` to your elements like :

```
.fancybox {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
#titles {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
#gradient {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10; /* lower for the gradient background */
}
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your gradient container is over the top of all other elements on your site. So when clicking - you're just clicking on the gradient container as opposed to the element that fires your fancy box function.

In order to fix this - you need to ensure the element you want to fire the fancy box script is on top and is clickable.

The best solution would be to create a wrapper div element that wraps around all of your site content and set the animated gradient on that wrapper instead. Then insert all of your images/logos etc inside that element. e.g.

```
<div class="wrapper"> <-- Apply your Gradient animation to this element -->
    <div class="titles"></div>
    <a class="fancy box"></a>
</div>
```

By following this method - you can ensure your fancy box element and all other site content is still clickable.

Comment: Thanks James. That helps make the fancybox useable, but because of the nesting of the divs, the fancybox thumbnail has now taken on the opacity of its parent container (the gradient). is there anyway to fix that or is that unavoidable with this combo?

Comment: the solution, it seems, could be as simple as moving the opacity css from the div to the colors of the gradient, but I can't seem to figure out how. thoughts?